# Invalid binary while uploading in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

This is third time I am going to upload my application onto iTunes. Current version of my app is 1.1, already published. Before submitting new version which is 1.2, I provided all required information as I provided earlier but when I submitted new binary, I mentioned 2.0 in info.plist by mistake. So I am bit confuses because apple is show invalid binary message because of versioning or is there something else. kindly help me because this is first time that I am facing this sort of issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: XCode Version? Support the iPhone 5 (Default-568h@2x.png)? Targeting our app for iOS..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hunting, find solution, i am targeting app for ios6.0 but making in xcode4.2. I made binary in xcode 4.5 and uploaded successfully and status change to Waiting For Review.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to upgrade to Xcode 4.5 to support iphone 5 resolution. If you build your project with an older version you'll get an error* when the file Default-568h@2x.png is present.

So.. **upgrade your Xcode**... or just simple **remove Default-568h@2x.png** (app will run in letterbox mode). More detail here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/153862-Good-to-know-iOS-4-5-6-and-invalid-binary

Answer (score 0):

No,2.0 is not a solution...You can try with 1.2 its not a issue but you can check other

important things like right provisioning profile in xcode selected,right provisioning file

downloaded etc etc.

Comment: I think i selected right provisioning profile as i selected earlier. what include in etc etc?

Comment: Check bundle identifier in code and in prvisioning profile when you create it on developet portal and then use in Itunes for submit App...